# Saving references to Screens, Objects, Variables, etc. VS creating new

Tags: performance, caching, libgdx

I'm wondering if it is better for performance to have a Class that initiates all required variables/objects for my Screens and then pass this class to the different screens, instead of always initiating everything in the Screen itself.

Then if something needs change, say I want to change the text in a label from "level 1" to "level 2" I'd just do:

```
//inside Screen
gameContext.getLevelLabel().setText("level 2"); 
//gameContext is the class everything is initialized in that gets //initialized on app launch
```

I am currently struggeling a lot with memory leaks/heavy gc usage and I think it's a lot due to the fact that I initiate so many local variables each time I switch between Screens (I already unload every asset and everything disposable).

**Another example** could be the UI background I use, I have 7 different Screens in my UI, but they all use the same background. Right now I Initiate that BG in their parentScreen that my Screens extend, but it is still initialized everytime I call `g.setScreen(new Screen(screen));` , which feels sub-optimal.

One option I thought of was to initiate all Screens on launch, and then when I swap Screens I just call `g.setScreen(g.getSettingScreen())`, i.e, I dont initiate the Screens all the time, but instead keep them in memory, and any fields that can change I refresh in `show()`. I'm not sure what is best for performance.

Comment: It's absolutely better for performance. The only reason not to is to save memory if you need to. Even then you can keep your screen around and only dispose of its high memory objects.

Comment: @Tenfour04 Thanks buddy